# How to use menu like FilterChip in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-3.0

Is there any way to achieve the following effect?

[Chips-Material Design 3](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/guidelines#dcf3eb06-5f81-4f7d-8299-e32a950d8572)

I try to use dropdownmenu, but failed

this is my code(flutter 3.3, useMaterial3: true):

ps: forgive my ugly english..

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<String> list = ['flutter', 'material', 'dart', 'django'];
  String selectedValue = 'flutter';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: selectedValue,
          // icon: Container(),
          underline: Container(),
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) => list
              .map((e) => FilterChip(
                    showCheckmark: true,
                    selected: e == selectedValue,
                    label: Text(e),
                    onSelected: (value) {},
                  ))
              .toList(),
          items: list
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e,
                    child: Text(e),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() => selectedValue = value!);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```